# How do I fix warning "The href attribute is required for an anchor to be keyboard accessible. Provide a valid, navigable address as the href value"?

Tags: reactjs

I have written code in JSX like below

```
            <div className="container">
                <ul className="con_list">
                    <li><a href="#">Home {s}&nbsp; </a></li>
                    <li> <a href="#"> Categories</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Comment: The error message appears to be perfectly clear. What don't you understand about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to write href="/" instead of href="#"

Comment: Thanks @Kashish Jaiswal, This is what I need because my project is underdevelopment. your answer helps me a lot .now its not getting any warnings